# What is this plant with large leaves?

Tags: identification

[image]Please identify the plant on the right of the photo. The plant is about a foot high with large leaves, 4 inches or more in length.  Photo taken in London in April

Comment: John, welcome! Please take the [tour] and browse our [help] to learn more about the site and the SE system in general. If you find an answer helpful, we usually don't comment (but it's not forbidden, of course), we "upvote" it by clicking the arrow/triangle next to it. And you as the asker may eventually "accept" the most helpful (to you) answer. You will find more about this in the [help] and on [meta]. Feel free to ask, if you need help.

Answer (score 5):

Symphytum orientale, common name white comfrey - its suffering from drought (not surprising, so is everything else in London UK at the moment), so if you want to keep it, water. You may not want to though - although it's very useful to bees and other insects for its pollen, it's quite difficult to get rid of once it's taken hold. http://wildflowerfinder.org.uk/Flowers/C/Comfrey(White)/Comfrey(White).htm

Answer (score 0):

I think one other might be possible...tough to go up against Bamboo!  But I'll have a go; Chenopodium album or  Lamb's Quarters...a cool edible weed.[lamb's quarters](http://www.ediblewildfood.com/lambs-quarters.aspx)

Comment: Take a closer look at the open flowers in the photo - they're at the top, leaning against the wall....maybe you didn't notice them, but they're not lambs quarter...

Comment: I am sure it is white comfrey.

Comment: Welp, hang my head and hunch over and tuck my tail, grins!  Dang, why did i not see those flowers.  Hey, at least there is no mistake?  Great job as always...Bamboo.  But if those flowers weren't there it DID look like Chenopodium...those flowers are kinda sorta OBVIOUS.  Great job!!

Comment: Well, those flowers were not immediately obvious, I only saw them myself under magnification....

Comment: Bamboo you are trying to make me feel better...they are right there had I spent a second more.  OOOhhhh  thought I knew this one, grins!  I do the knee jerk reflex, sigh.  Sit in lotus position, close eyes, breathe in through nose and out through a straw....huggs!